# Building Custom SBT plugin, getting error: object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe

Tags: scala, sbt

**tl;dr** I'm trying to have my custom plugin a) automatically pull the GitVersioning plugin with it, and b) have access to variables such as `git.baseVersion`. Doing it the best way I know how is giving me import errors.

I am trying to write a custom plugin, similar to the [one here](https://engineering.sharethrough.com/blog/2015/09/23/capturing-common-config-with-an-sbt-parent-plugin/).

My `BaseSettingsPlugin.scala` looks like:

```
package com.sp.sbt

import sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.GitVersioning
import sbt._


/**
 * Provides base settings for all of our projects
 */
object BaseSettingsPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

/**
 * Defines all settings/tasks that get automatically imported,
 * when the plugin is enabled
 */
  object autoImport {
    lazy val libraryVersions = settingKey[Map[Symbol, String]]("Common versions to be used for dependencies")
  }

  import autoImport._

  // allow the plug-in to be included automatically
  override def trigger: PluginTrigger = allRequirements

  override def requires = GitVersioning

  /**
   * Provide default settings
   */
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",

    organization := "com.sp",

    libraryVersions := Map(
      'bijection          ->            "0.8.1",
      'elastic4s          ->            "1.7.4",
      'ficus              ->            "1.1.2",
      'finatra            ->            "2.1.0",
      'hikari             ->            "2.4.1",
      'h2                 ->            "1.4.189",
      'mysql              ->            "5.1.36",
      'redis              ->            "6.29.0",
      'scala              ->            scalaVersion.value,
      'scalatest          ->            "2.2.3",
      'scoverage          ->            "1.1.1",
      'slick              ->            "3.1.1",
      'slickJoda          ->            "2.1.0",
      'specs2             ->            "2.3.13",
      'swagger            ->            "0.3.0",
      'typesafe           ->            "1.3.0"
    )
  )
}
```

When I try to build my custom plugin, I get the following error message:

```
[error] BaseSettingsPlugin.scala:10: object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe
[error] import com.typesafe.sbt.GitVersioning
[error]                     ^
[error] BaseSettingsPlugin.scala:40: not found: value GitVersioning
[error]   override def requires = GitVersioning
```

The second error message is to be expected, because of the failing import statement.

If I move the `import com.typesafe.sbt.GitVersioning` to my `build.sbt` file, I no longer receive the import error, but I do continue to receive the second (not found) error.

What I'm really trying to do is make it so that I can have the following code block in my custom plugin:

```
git.useGitDescribe := true, // if this is true, then it uses the version number suggested by $> git describe
  // if this is false, it combines the baseVersion and the commit hash of the current commit
git.baseVersion := "0.0.0",
git.gitUncommittedChanges := false,
git.gitTagToVersionNumber := {
  case VersionRegex(v,"") => Some(v)
  case VersionRegex(v,"SNAPSHOT") => Some(s"$v-SNAPSHOT")
  case VersionRegex(v,s) => Some(s"$v-$s-SNAPSHOT")
  case _ => None
```

}

Also, for clarification, here's `build.sbt`

```
// we hide the existing definition for setReleaseVersion to replace it with our own
import sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations.{setReleaseVersion=>_,_}
import com.typesafe.sbt.GitVersioning

sbtPlugin := true

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"            // This overrides the scalaVersion from BaseSettingsPlugin

name := "base-settings"

libraryDependencies <++= libraryVersions { v => Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % v('scala),
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % v('scala),
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % v('typesafe)
)}

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(GitVersioning)
  .settings(packageSettings: _*)
```

Comment: I think you're missing `sbtPlugin := true` in your build.sbt

Comment: @m-z i have `sbtPlugin := true` in `build.sbt`, but didn't post the contents of the file. i've updated now.

Comment: (just in case) did you actually add the plugin as a dependency in your sbt or plugins config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make sure that the GitVersioning plugin was not only available to the build process, but also to my plugin specifically.

To `build.sbt`, I added:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5")
```

Upon doing this, `sbt-git` was available to my plugin.

Comment: You've got a dedicaded file to add plugins named `plugins.sbt` in the project directory